# la propiedad background-image no cambia

Tags: html, css, css3, web, design

Estoy tratando de que la imagen de fondo cambie dependiendo de en que dispositivo se vea pero siempre carga la imagen que esta en la propiedad `only screen and (min-width: 768px)`. No sé por que pasa esto

```css
html, body, .body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .body {
        /* imagen de tablet */
            background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522204523234-8729aa6e3d5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80");
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: #a4448b;
        }

        /* For desktop */
        @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            .body {
            /* imagen de manos en el teclado*/
                background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80");
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="body"></div>
```

Comment: Que pasa si agregas `!important`?

Comment: Si te está funcionando, lo que pasa es que a lo mejor no como esperas. Con la regla `min-width: 768px` le estás diciendo al navegador que cargue la imagen de la **mediaquerie** en dispositivos que al menos tengan **768px** de ancho ( > 768px). Por lo que te va a mostrar la de las "manos con el ordenador" en pantallas superiores a **768px** y la de "las plantas" en dispositivos inferiores a **768px**

Answer (score 0):

Sirve con ponerle un `min-width` y un `max-width` al que será tu imagen responsiva.

```
<style>
html, body, .body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .body {
        background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522204523234-8729aa6e3d5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80");
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #a4448b;
        }

    /* For desktop */
    @media only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:768px) {
        .body {
        /* imagen de manos en el teclado*/
            background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80");
        }
    }
</style>
```